# error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'path_to_project\\node_modules\\prisma\\query_engine-windows.dll.node'

Tags: javascript, package, yarnpkg, prisma

I installed Prisma and I run `npx primsa db push` it pushed all tables to database successfully, after that I run `npx prisma generate` it tried to install @prisma/client and it fails with this error message:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'path_to_project\node_modules\prisma\query_engine-windows.dll.node'

I tried to remove `node_modules` and re-install all modules but it not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install `@prisma/client` manually with `yarn add @prisma/client` then run `npx prisma generate` it works perfectlly.

Answer (score 29):

If you are running **nextjs** server. Close the server and try running the command again.

```
$ npx prisma generate
```

Answer (score 6):

Closing all processes and re-running the command worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when using `npx prisma generate` command. I had to close the next js server that was using the prisma client. Try closing any development servers you have that uses the prisma client and then try running the command again.

Comment: I have issue with this command, `$ npx prisma migrate dev` . still loading

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error type with a different package. In my case the thing that was causing the error was because it couldn't access the folder while the app was still running ie. from this issue https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2685

This was following npm cache clean --force not resolving it.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you.
I killed the prisma client and the app, then run my command and worked without issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had killed the running backend frameworks (NestJS/Express) which were using Prisama. And try again with `npx prisama generate`.
It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but after installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Stopping my docker container running and closing vs code and reopening it, solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same error and same solution for some reason the folders/files that need to be modified conflict with each other, but if you stop the Node process serving your project, you can migrate without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , Stop the running docker container and things work fine again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, my solution is don't generate prisma when you running your app. Try generate your model data when you not running your app

Answer (score 0):

Close Other Applications: Ensure that no other applications are using the Prisma files or the `.prisma/client` directory. Close any editors, terminals, or applications that might be accessing these files.

open tabs was holding a lock on the file or directory, preventing the operation from completing successfully.

> close all tab

> or

> stop your npm server before running prisma generate `ctrl+c`

`npx prisma generate`

Answer (score 0):

when you restart your server don't reload your page then run npx prisma generate, i promise it will work perfect, but if you reload your page, and you run the npx prisma generate it will give you error